# SQL Server connection issue (ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am learning ASP.NET MVC, from official site.

When I reach at [this tutorial page](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller), after creating Movies controller, when I navigate to url: localhost://xxxx/movies/index I got an exception.

Exception Message is :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details

**My system details are:-**

- Windows 10 pro (64 bit)
- Visual studio for community 2015
- SQL Server 2014 (64 bit)

**Connection string in web.config file is this**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=&quot;|DataDirectory|\aspnet-world movies-20150825083408.mdf&quot;;Initial Catalog=&quot;aspnet-world movies-20150825083408&quot;;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The exception is in this action method at line #20

```
    public ActionResult Index()
Line 19:         {
Line 20:             return View(db.Movies.ToList());
Line 21:         }
```

Comment: Please show the code relating to your SQL connection string from the web config, removing all credentials info obviously.

Comment: Did you complete step 5?

Answer (score 1):

it think the issue is with connection string.

when the tutorial was created it was using SQL server 2012 localDB then connection string was `"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;"`

but in VS 2015 SQL server 2014 it is changed to `"(localdb)\ProjectsV12;"`

**Update:** Microsoft again changed the localDb name in VS 2015 
Use `"(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;"`

so try to change connection string to

```
"(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf"
```

and try running. good luck

you can find the working code hear : [GettingStartedWithASPNETMVC5](https://github.com/JophyJob/GettingStartedWithASPNETMVC5)

Comment: hey Jophy job thanks for reply
i tried to change the connection  string as you suggest but following exception has been caught.

Keyword not supported: '(localdb)\projectsv12;attachdbfilename'.

Comment: the problem is at this action method:

public ActionResult Index()
         {
             return View(db.Movies.ToList());
}

Comment: Sorry Microsoft again changed the localDB database Name . please use "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB"